# variable length data types inside a buffer in C

Tags: c, serialization, bit-manipulation

What would be the easiest way to handle serialization of data of variable number of bits put into a uint8 buffer?

For example, the first 4 bits are one variable, then 1 bit is a boolean, another one is 3 bits long. Then you have an array of 8 bytes, and then a 13 bit variable and so on. All this would be written into an unsigned char buffer to be sent over a socket.

The variables data types are sometimes not aligning on 8 bit -16 bit boundaries, they have weird # of bits like 7 bits long, 13 bits long, 3 bits long, etc.

Would it best to write something in C for this, or to use a third party library?

Comment: What?  XML isn't good enough for you?  :)

Comment: I'd definitely use some part of the buffer as a header for every variable. The header would store how long the data type is and maybe an enumerated int to represent the data type. Then, you could write a conversion function to typecast when you want to use it.

Comment: @infixed: You cannot use XML on all platforms! XML is bloat.

Comment: @Olaf It was obviously a joke, see the smiley. Clearly the OP is trying to create a very compact format, and XML is the antithesis of this.

Comment: @olaf But bloat makes it easier.  Actually the simplest is to bloat it up to 1 ASCII character per bit.  I suggest '0' and '1', with a third character say 'x' as a field separator.  10x11010101x100001x.   (at least I didn't suggest Google Protocol Buffers)

Comment: Are all these sizes known by both the sender and receiver, or do you need to be able to unpack all the different sized fields dynamically?

Comment: @Barmar They are known by the sender and receiver and this will run on an 8 bit microcontroller

Comment: Then C code with shifting and masking is the way to do it. I don't know offhand if there's a library that does this.

Comment: Look up TLV (Type Length Value) encoding techniques.  You might do the 'type' at the level of each message, so message type 1 indicates 4+1+3+8x8+13 bits which can be unpacked without much in the way of a length.  Or you might encode each set of bits into a multiple of 8 bits and prefix them with 'type bits' and 'length N' where N is encoded in a suitable number of bits, etc.  The options are endless; it depends on how much diversity there is in the messages, and the relative costs of lots of customer encoders and decoders vs one generic encoder and one generic decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tough part really is the encoding of the length.

For instance, if you never had a length greater than 255 bits (assuming that there is no zero bit option), then you would take the next 8 bits in the stream to get the length, then that number of bits to get the value.

You could also do it in segments.  use zero as a length implies a length greater than 255.  So you read in 255 bits, then prefix those to the next segment (who has a similarly defined length), so you can keep chaining as long as you want,

If you wanted to get fancier, and you had a known set of bit lengths to deal with, you could make a [Huffman Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to represent the length, then alternate the Huffman code with the actual bit values.

But that would entail knowing the possible length ahead of time.  But you could reserve a Huffman code to say 'chain to next' too

You could even use Huffman coding to implement my ASCII scheme from the comments above, but substitute a Huffman code for the '0','1', and 'x'

a sequence of a single zero bit  means the next bit in the field is '0'

a sequence of one followed by another one means the next bit is a '1'

a sequence of one followed by a zero could mean the same as 'x, end of field